# How do you alias an imported package in a JSP file?

Tags: java, jsp, import, package

I have a JSP file that has a few imports at the top:

```
<%@ page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
```

However, I have an issue because of a prior import resulting in a collision error with another import.

Is it possible to alias this import like you would in a traditional Java class?

```
import org.json.JSONObject jsOb
```

**Note**:

I know that there are no traditional aliasing mechanisms in Java. I just was not sure if there were some tag-based mechanism that would suffice. Additionally, using a fully qualified path to the package will not work, since the import is actually failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any aliasing mechanisms for packages in Java. The following is obviously illegal in Java:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.mypackage.JSONObject;
```

If there is a conflict in names in Java using 2 or more classes sharing the same name, you have to distinguish them using the full package name:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

// code

JSONObject json = ...;
com.mypackage.JSONObject jsonObject = new com.mypackage.JSONObject(json);
```

The same analogy has to be used in the Java Servlet Pages. The best solution would be to avoid those classes with the same name if possible.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I was missing that. Defining the full name solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, welcome. One of the major disadvantages of Java is the verbosity, especially in the packages naming. I wouldn't wonder if you end up with a full-name class and package definition taking a whole line :D I rather keep the names short and create more classes.